# How to force no whitespace in dot notation

Tags: parsing, yacc, ply

I'm attempting to implement an existing scripting language using Ply. Everything has been alright until I hit a section with dot notation being used on objects. For most operations, whitespace doesn't matter, so I put it in the ignore list. "3+5" works the same as "3 + 5", etc. However, in the existing program that uses this scripting language (which I would like to keep this as accurate to as I can), there are situations where spaces cannot be inserted, for example "this.field.array[5]" can't have any spaces between the identifier and the dot or bracket. Is there a way to indicate this in the parser rule without having to handle whitespace not being important everywhere else? Or am I better off building these items in the lexer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you do something in the lexical scanner to pass whitespace through to the parser, there's not a lot the parser can do.

It would be useful to know why `this.field.array[5]` must be written without spaces. (Or, maybe, mostly without spaces: perhaps `this.field.array[ 5 ]` is acceptable.) Is there some other interpretation if there are spaces? Or is it just some misguided aesthetic judgement on the part of the scripting language's designer?

The second case is a lot simpler. If the only possibilities are a correct parse without space or a syntax error, it's only necessary to validate the expression after it's been recognised by the parser. A simple validation function would simply check that the starting position of each token (available as `p.lexpos(i)` where `p` is the action function's parameter and `i` is the index of the token the the production's RHS) is precisely the starting position of the previous token plus the length of the previous token.

One possible reason to require the name of the indexed field to immediately follow the `.` is to simplify the lexical scanner, in the event that it is desired that otherwise reserved words be usable as member names. In theory, there is no reason why any arbitrary identifier, including language keywords, cannot be used as a member selector in an expression like `object.field`. The `.` is an unambiguous signal that the following token is a member name, and not a different syntactic entity. JavaScript, for example, allows arbitrary identifiers as member names; although it might confuse readers, nothing stops you from writing `obj.if = true`.

That's a big of a challenge for the lexical scanner, though. In order to correctly analyse the input stream, it needs to be aware of the context of each identifier; if the identifier immediately follows a `.` used as a member selector, the keyword recognition rules must be suppressed. This can be done using lexical states, available in most lexer generators, but it's definitely a complication. Alternatively, one can adopt the rule that the member selector is a single token, including the `.`. In that case, `obj.if` consists of two tokens (`obj`, an `IDENTIFIER`, and `.if`, a `SELECTOR`). The easiest implementation is to recognise `SELECTOR` using a pattern like `\.[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*`. (That's not what JavaScript does. In JavaScript, it's not only possible to insert arbitrary whitespace between the `.` and the selector, but even comments.)

Based on a comment by the OP, it seems plausible that this is part of the reasoning for the design of the original scripting language, although it doesn't explain the prohibition of whitespace before the `.` or before a `[` operator.

There are languages which resolve grammatical ambiguities based on the presence or absence of surrounding whitespace, for example in disambiguating operators which can be either unary or binary (Swift); or distinguishing between the use of `|` as a boolean operator from its use as an absolute value expression (uncommon but see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28408/lexing-and-parsing-a-language-with-juxtaposition-as-an-operator); or even distinguishing the use of `(...)` in grouping expressions from their use in a function call. (Awk, for example). So it's certainly possible to imagine a language in which the `.` and/or `[` tokens have different interpretations depending on the presence or absence of surrounding whitespace.

If you need to distinguish the cases of tokens with and without surrounding whitespace so that the grammar can recognise them in different ways, then you'll need to either pass whitespace through as a token, which contaminates the entire grammar, or provide two (or more) different versions of the tokens whose syntax varies depending on whitespace. You could do that with regular expressions, but it's probably easier to do it in the lexical action itself, again making use of the lexer state. Note that the lexer state includes `lexdata`, the input string itself, and `lexpos`, the index of the next input character; the index of the first character in the current token is in the token's `lexpos` attribute. So, for example, a token was preceded by whitespace if `t.lexpos == 0 or t.lexer.lexdata[t.lexpos-1].isspace()`, and it is followed by whitespace if `t.lexer.lexpos == len(t.lexer.lexdata) or t.lexer.lexdata[t.lexer.lexpos].isspace()`.

Once you've divided tokens into two or more token types, you'll find that you really don't need the division in most productions. So you'll usually find it useful to define a new non-terminal for each token type representing all of the whitespace-context variants of that token; then, you only need to use the specific variants in productions where it matters.

Comment: You are right that spaces within the brackets are fine. You can say "this.field.array[ 5]", but not "this .field.array[5]" or "this.field.array [5]". Attempting to do that gets variations on "Invalid field syntax used" or "Invalid use of the reserved word 'field' in script". It's actually pretty consistently implemented, which is why I was hoping to encode it as a simple rule.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how it goes about breaking up the code into tokens other than what I can guess by putting code into the program and seeing what error messages I get. I'm not certain if it's tokenizing the items into something it likes and then failing on the parser, or if it's getting caught earlier.

Comment: Since this is a bit of a toy project for me, I'll probably just implement it the "incorrect" way for now, and make a note that I may want to check for better correctness later. Thank you.

Comment: @sean: based on the error message you mention above ("invalid use of reserved word"), I added a couple of paragraphs to the answer.